# prolog: Trying to model equation with 3 rules - how to get prolog to match the right one?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to model a simple 3 variable equation (like Ohm's law) where RESULT=NUMERATOR/DENOMINATOR. (But actually in my case, I am using purely integers).

I have created three rules; which appear to work fine if I define them on their own and call them with the 'hole' variable which appears on the left of the 'is', but I can't figure out how to get the appropriate rule to be called, depending on where I place variables rather than integers...

Here are the rules I have come up with (in the order I have defined them):

```
equation(RESULT, NUMERATOR, DENOMINATOR) :-
        RESULT is NUMERATOR // DENOMINATOR.

equation(RESULT, NUMERATOR, DENOMINATOR) :-
         NUMERATOR is DENOMINATOR * RESULT.

equation(RESULT, NUMERATOR, DENOMINATOR) :-
         DENOMINATOR is NUMERATOR // RESULT.
```

I can get the first rule to work:

```
| ?- equation(RESULT, 200, 10).

RESULT = 20 ? 

yes
```

But then attempting to move the 'hole' from the 'RESULT' slot to any of the other two doesn't seem to match the other rules:

```
| ?- equation(20, N, 10).      
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(is)/2)
| ?- equation(20, 200, D). 
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(is)/2)
```

I'm new to prolog, so probably going about this the wrong way...any pointers on how I could program this ?

Version Info Follows:

```
GNU Prolog 1.3.0
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2007 Daniel Diaz
| ?-
```

Comment: why are you using integer division (i.e. //) ?

Comment: Actually: for the problem I am trying to solve - I know that the inputs are integers (actually trying this: http://www.newscientist.com/article/mg21829171.400-enigma-number-1749.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always the first rule that is called, resulting in those errors when variables are not instantiated.

You could write

```
equation(RESULT, NUMERATOR, DENOMINATOR) :-
        nonvar(NUMERATOR), nonvar(DENOMINATOR), !,
        RESULT is NUMERATOR // DENOMINATOR.

equation(RESULT, NUMERATOR, DENOMINATOR) :-
        nonvar(DENOMINATOR), nonvar(RESULT), !,
        NUMERATOR is DENOMINATOR * RESULT.

equation(RESULT, NUMERATOR, DENOMINATOR) :-
        nonvar(NUMERATOR), nonvar(RESULT), !,
        DENOMINATOR is NUMERATOR // RESULT.
```

or, much better, enter [constraint programming](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.8%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/clpqr.html%27%29%29)

```
:- [library(clpr)].
ohm(V, R, I) :- {V = R * I}.
```

that yields

```
17 ?- ohm(20,N,10).
N = 2.0 .
```

*EDIT*:

```
~$ gprolog
GNU Prolog 1.3.0
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2007 Daniel Diaz

| ?- [user].
compiling user for byte code...
ohm(V,R,I) :- V #= R * I.

user compiled, 2 lines read - 338 bytes written, 23339 ms

(4 ms) yes
| ?- ohm(1,10,10).

no
| ?- ohm(V,10,10).

V = 100

yes
| ?- ohm(5,X,10). 

no
| ?- ohm(30,X,10).
```

Comment: Thanks very much: some weirdness here though: equation(1,10,10) is apparently 'no.'..... but equation(10//10,10,10) is 'yes'... I don't seem to have the constraint libraries (but those look great, I'll look into them).

Comment: What Prolog are you using ?

Comment: GnuProlog has a good *finite* constraint solver. It's OK to use for integer values - but it's possible to adapt it to fixed point arithmetic.

Comment: Great - that does work - and thanks for introducing me to the constraint thingy !

Comment: When trying out the given example, it seems to hang on my machine in the step `compiling user for byte code... `. Do you have any pointers on how I troubleshoot this? I used gnu-prolog v. 1.4.5 (installed via homebrew on mac os. 10.15, 64bit).